# extract specific data from log file line with regex then compare with timestamp from other lines and generate csv file

Tags: regex, perl, csv, scripting, timestamp

I'm new to Perl and I have a problem merging data together to a new file.

I have a log file (example below) including lines with (RSSI values and timestamp) and lines with (GPS positions (latitude, longitude) and timestamp). The GPS positions triggered more often than the RSSI values, hence the log file includes more lines with GPS positions than lines with RSSI values.

I have to find the GPS line with the right timestamp matching each RSSI timestamp.

The timestamps have `99:99:99.999` format. To compare the timestamps I only need `99:99:99` format.

In the end I want to generate a new CSV file with the timestamps in 99:99:99 format, the RSSI values and the corresponding GPS positions, discarding useless GPS positions. The CSV file should contain (timestamp, RSSI, latitude, longitude). The log file looks like this. (In this example the GPS position doesn't change but in real they will.)

```
# .log file
# first rssi timestamp is 10:23:05.746 (hour:minute:second.microsecond) and RSSI value -91
Line 167: 0.11036     0   25.11.2014 10:23:05.746  01.01.1970 00:53:55.545  CON.NAD.CINTERION     nadProc.NAD_Run_AT_Cmds         info   55     NADCinterion::handleSMONI(3441): SMONI LTE_RSSI -91 -91
Line 1747: 0.12577     0   25.11.2014 10:23:07.967  01.01.1970 00:53:57.766  CON.NAD.CINTERION     nadProc.NAD_Run_AT_Cmds         info   55     NADCinterion::handleSMONI(3441): SMONI LTE_RSSI -92 -92
Line 2096: 0.12925     0   25.11.2014 10:23:11.744  01.01.1970 00:54:01.544  CON.NAD.CINTERION     nadProc.NAD_Run_AT_Cmds         info   55     NADCinterion::handleSMONI(3441): SMONI LTE_RSSI -93 -93
Line 3472: 0.14272     0   25.11.2014 10:23:15.745  01.01.1970 00:54:05.545  CON.NAD.CINTERION     nadProc.NAD_Run_AT_Cmds         info   55     NADCinterion::handleSMONI(3441): SMONI LTE_RSSI -92 -92
Line 4915: 0.15681     0   25.11.2014 10:23:17.965  01.01.1970 00:54:07.766  CON.NAD.CINTERION     nadProc.NAD_Run_AT_Cmds         info   55     NADCinterion::handleSMONI(3441): SMONI LTE_RSSI -94 -94
# first GPS timestamp is 10:23:05.716 (hour:minute:second.microsecond) and GPS position 11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452
Line 194: 0.11062     0   25.11.2014 10:23:05.716  01.01.1970 00:53:55.515  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 819: 0.11672     0   25.11.2014 10:23:06.715  01.01.1970 00:53:56.514  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 1443: 0.12281     0   25.11.2014 10:23:07.716  01.01.1970 00:53:57.515  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 2538: 0.13558     0   25.11.2014 10:23:08.714  01.01.1970 00:54:04.514  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 2738: 0.13558     0   25.11.2014 10:23:11.714  01.01.1970 00:54:04.514  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 3324: 0.14130     0   25.11.2014 10:23:15.714  01.01.1970 00:54:05.514  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 4261: 0.15048     0   25.11.2014 10:23:17.114  01.01.1970 00:54:06.914  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
Line 4694: 0.15466     0   25.11.2014 10:23:17.813  01.01.1970 00:54:07.614  BL.POSITIONING        navi.DEF_THR                    debug  98     PositionNLAdapter < pos:11.38172906823456,48.78751751035452 heading: 156.0113220214844 speed:0km/h
```

1. I have to get the right line with LTE_RSSI `$line =~ /RSSI/`, then from that line `$lines_rssi` the timestamp `$rssi_timestamp` and RSSI value `$lte_rssi` with a regex `m/(\-\d+$)/`.
2. Get the right line with the GPS position and timestamp BL.POSITIONING `$line =~ m/BL.POSITIONING/`, then from that line `$lines_gps` the timestamp `$gps_timestamp` and corresponding GPS position `$latitude` and `$longitude` with a regex `m/pos:(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)/`.
3. Format the timestamps from `99:99:99.999` to `99:99:99` for comparison.
4. Take the first modified timestamp from the RSSI line and compare it to the modified timestamps from the GPS lines and, when matching a timestamp, take this GPS positions from that line.
5. Print out CSV file with modified RSSI timestamp, RSSI value, GPS position from matching GPS line (see point 4).

My code looks like this. It prints out all RSSI timestamps and values, and all GPS timestamps and positions but without comparing the timestamps with each other. And then prints only one timestamp, RSSI value, latitude, longitude

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Geben Sie den Namen der log Datei ein: " ;
my $log =<STDIN>;
open(LOG, $log) || die "Log nicht gefunden";

my $rssi_timestamp;      #rssi timestamp in format dd:dd:dd.ddd
my $lte_rssi;            #rssi value
my $gps_timestamp;       #gps timestamp ind format dd:dd:dd.ddd
my $latitude;            #gps latitude
my $longitude;           #gps longitude
my $lines_rssi;          #one complete line with rssi
my $lines_gps;           #one complete line with gps
my $gps_timestamp_mod;   #modified gps timestamp in format dd:dd:dd
my $rssi_timestamp_mod;  #modified rssi timestamp in format dd:dd:dd

while (my $line = <LOG>)  
{ 
  if ($line =~ /RSSI/) #find right line containing rssi value (regex RSSI)
  {
    $lines_rssi = $line;
    $lines_rssi =~ m/(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})/; #find matching timestamp pattern with regex
    $rssi_timestamp = $1; 
    print "$rssi_timestamp,";

    $rssi_timestamp =~ m/(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})/; #modify rssi timestamp format from dd:dd:dd.ddd to dd:dd:dd
    $rssi_timestamp_mod = $1;
    print "$rssi_timestamp_mod,";

    $lines_rssi =~ m/(\-\d+$)/; #find rssi value with regex
    $lte_rssi = $1;
    print "$lte_rssi\n"; 
  }
  if ($line =~ m/BL.POSITIONING/) #find line with GPS position with regex
  {
    $lines_gps = $line;
    $lines_gps =~ m/(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3})/; # find matching timestamp in gps line
    $gps_timestamp = $1;

    $gps_timestamp =~ m/(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})/;
    $gps_timestamp_mod = $1;

    if ($gps_timestamp_mod == $rssi_timestamp_mod) # here i want to compare the 2 modified timestamps with each other to find the right gps line but it doesn't work
    {
      $lines_gps =~ m/pos:(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)/;
      $latitude = $2;
      $longitude = $1;
      print "$gps_timestamp,$gps_timestamp_mod,$latitude,$longitude\n";
    }
  }
}
```

The CSV file should look like (timestamp, rssi, latitude, longitude).

Only the timestamps from RSSI values should be here (10:23:05, 10:23:07, 10:23:11, 10:23:15, 10:23:17) discarding the GPS lines with timestamps at (10:23:06, 10:23:08, and one of the 10:23:17):

```
10:23:05,-91,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:07,-92,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:11,-93,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:15,-92,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:17,-94,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

@Borodin: Thanks a lot for the code. It works perfect !
Furthermore like you mentioned i am also thinking of interpolation of the GPS coordinates like it is explained in this dokument with formular (1) and (2) on page 2 [Polynomial interpolation of GPS satellite
coordinates](http://acc.igs.org/orbits/orbit-interp_gpssoln06.pdf)

How complicated will be the interpolation within the code ?

Comment: Okay I understand. So your program prints the relevant fields from *all* the input records but you're not sure how to tie each RSSI record with the relevant GPS record? How do you want to determine the matching GPS record? The one with the closest time, or the first one with a later time, or something else? Are the RSSI records and GPS records in the same file? How big is the file likely to be?

Comment: Also, please say what version of Perl you are working with? And it is best if you answer these questions by editing your post rather than in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. Instead of removing the fractional seconds, I've written a subroutine `epoch_seconds` that uses the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) module to convert the time (including milliseconds) *and* the date into floating-point seconds since the start of 1970. That will avoid any issues with times around midnight.

The entire file is read and the relevant data is store in two hashes: `%rssi` and `%gps`, indexed by the floating-point timestamp. Then every element of `%rssi` is paired with an element of `%gps` by finding the element with the least absolute difference in timestamps by using the `min_by` function from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::UtilsBy). Then it is just necessary to print all the data in both elements found.

You may have to install `List::UtilsBy` as it is not a core module.

Note that the timestamp that is actually reported in the output is the value that `$report_time` is set to. I have stripped the date and the fractional seconds to make it the same as your example, but you can modify that as you wish.

It occurs to me that it would be simple to do a linear interpolation between the GPS coordinates either side of the RSSI data to get a better accuracy, if that would be of use.

I hope this helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use List::UtilsBy qw/ min_by /;

print "Geben Sie den Namen der log Datei ein: ";
chomp(my $log_file = <STDIN>);
open my $log_fh, '<', $log_file or die "Log nicht gefunden: $!";

my $out_file = 'logfile.csv';

my (%rssi, %gps);

while (<$log_fh>) {

  next if /^#/;

  if (/LTE_RSSI/) {     # find right line containing rssi value (regex RSSI)

    next unless /( \d+\.\d+\.\d+ \s+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ )/x;
    my $timestamp = $1;
    my $timestamp_seconds = epoch_seconds($timestamp);
    my ($report_time) = $timestamp =~ /(\d+:\d+:\d+)/;

    next unless /(\-\d+$)/;    # find RSSI value with regex
    $rssi{$timestamp_seconds} = [$report_time, $1];
  }
  elsif (/BL\.POSITIONING/) {    # find line with GPS position with regex

    next unless /( \d+\.\d+\.\d+ \s+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+ )/x;
    my $timestamp = $1;
    my $timestamp_seconds = epoch_seconds($timestamp);

    next unless /pos:(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)/;
    $gps{$timestamp_seconds} = [$2,$1];
  }
}

open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for output: $!};

for my $rssi_seconds (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %rssi) {
  my $gps_seconds = min_by { abs($_ - $rssi_seconds) } keys %gps;
  print $out_fh join(',', @{ $rssi{$rssi_seconds} }, @{ $gps{$gps_seconds} }), "\n";
}

sub epoch_seconds {
  my ($date_time) = @_;
  die unless shift =~ /(.+)\.(.+)/;
  Time::Piece->strptime($1, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')->epoch . ".$2";
}
```

**output**

```
10:23:05,-91,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:07,-92,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:11,-93,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:15,-92,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
10:23:17,-94,48.78751751035452,11.38172906823456
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, thanks a lot! The code does exactly what i want. Even matching the GPS Record to the RSSI Record with the closest time. A interpolation between the GPS coordinates would be nice. I was also thinking about that. Do you think it would be simple ? I am thinking about of using the polynomial function used in this document (see end of my original post).